# how to stop creating multiple url of product

Tags: magento-2.1, url, store-view, store-id

Product URL created for all stores even I have  disable the stores 1,2,3,4. I just need store 2. but while uploading the product the nos of product URL created for all stores(in url_rewrite table). If deleted those store 1,3,4 the store not found error getting.

Kindly help as i am new in magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Website ID in website column as per your store Id. While uploading products.